# Android kotlin code for getting the current location details?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-location-services

Please provide me the android kotlin example code for getting the current location using FusedLocationProviderClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code..

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
            val latitude = location.latitude
            val longitude = location.longitude
        }
}
```

##### Note

You must declare location permissions in your `Manifest.xml` file as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1"
```